nth root of a positive semi-definite operator on a Hilbert space
Given a positive semidefinite operator on a Hilbert space, I can tell by the spectral theorem that:
$$T = \int \lambda d P_T(\lambda)$$
Where $P_T(\lambda)$ is the spectral measure associated with T. 
Is it correct to say that the operator: $$ S = \int \sqrt[n]{\lambda} dP_T(\lambda)$$
Is a unique positive semidefinite operator with $S^n = T$? This seems to be the obvious approach, but it sounds too good to be true.

It is true. What is your doubt about it?

By the way, you should consider accepting some of the answers you received for your questions if you find the answers to be satisfactory. None of the questions you asked has an accepted answer, even though lots of them have answers that are upvoted and/or should be satisfactory. Otherwise people might be disinclined to put in the effort to answer your questions in the future.

Thank you, I did not realize that, and I'll do it later.
It's just that the concept of the operator being equal to an integral is kind of perplexing to me and I don't really understand how to use it properly.

One way I think about it is to not regard $dP_T$ as a measure by itself, but as a collection of complex measures $\langle dP_T x, y \rangle$ indexed by $x, y \in H$ that’s sesquilinear in $x$ and $y$. It doesn’t really help with this specific question. (This question hinges more on how $dP$ is obtained in the first place, namely through Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem applied to continuous functional calculus.) But it does help, at least for me, in understanding what an integral w.r.t. $dP$ means.
